# How can I convert my OIDC client implementation using the "authorization code" flow to an OAuth2 client-server setup?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

How can I convert my OIDC client implementation using the "authorization code" flow to an OAuth2 client-server setup?

Currently, I have an OIDC client created using the `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` to authorize a user across an **OAuth2** authorization server. However, for my project, I need to convert this to an **OAuth2 client-server setup**. The goal is for the new service (which includes the client and server components) to create a token and share it with the user after successful authentication. Additionally, I require the refreshtoken/validate/jwks endpoints to be available for the new authentication server (jdbc token store).

I have attempted to add the spring oauth2-server dependency and configure it in several ways, but I have not been successful in meeting the requirement. I have also tried setting up a custom jdbc token store and creating the endpoints manually, but I am unsure if this is the best approach. Can someone provide guidance on the best approach to implement such a service?

Comment: I konw OAuth2 client, OAuth2 resource-server and OAuth2 authorization-server  but this OAuth2 client-server is something totally new to me. Can you clarify this concept?